# Website renders differently on Safari than Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, sprite

I am working to add on to an open source project that makes a pac man game in html, css, and js. The website renders properly on Chrome but does not work on Safari. Both work properly on screens with a larger width but less width causes an issue on Safari with how the sprite map is parsed and displayed. Since I did not develop the program myself, I do not know specifically what is causing the issue but I have a couple leads. I cannot figure out to solve this issue, so any help would be very much appreciated!

[Expected behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cojUD.png)
[Unexpected behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7K9V.jpg)

How part of how sprites are rendered from the sprite map:

```
  width: 3.2rem;
  height: 2.6rem;
  background-image: url("sprites.png");
  background-position: -26rem -3.2rem;
}

@media (max-width: 600px), (max-height: 700px) {
  .live {
    background-image: url(sprites_small.png);
  }
}

.wall {
  background-image: url("map.png");
  z-index: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 600px), (max-height: 700px) {
  .wall {
    background-image: url("small_map.png");
  }
}

.blank {
  background-color: black;
}

.wall > * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  border: .2rem solid #161693;
  border-radius: 80%;
  z-index: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 600px), (max-height: 700px) {
  .points::after,
  .yellow-visible,
  .red-visible,
  .pink-visible,
  .blue-visible,
  .orange-visible {
    background-image: url("sprites_small.png");
  }
}

.yellow-visible {
  background-position: var(--yellow-sprite-x) var(--yellow-sprite-y);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform var(--yellow-animation-length) linear;
  transition: -webkit-transform var(--yellow-animation-length) linear;
  transition: transform var(--yellow-animation-length) linear;
  transition: transform var(--yellow-animation-length) linear, -webkit-transform var(--yellow-animation-length) linear;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Here is the full project for more code I've been using: https://github.com/dominikgorczyca/Pac-Man
The website for this project is: https://dominikgorczyca.github.io/Pac-Man/

Thanks again for any help!

Comment: Just after a quick look of the images I can tell that it has to do with your back image position. Looks like on safari it is attempting to tile the back image NOT starting at the top left corner of your sprite element block. If it works on safari in large screen I would also say inspect the element and make sure the element sets its new background image url AND inherits the properties that define its background position

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Just wondering which lines of code you are referring to for the changes and what you recommend changing again I am a little bit confused since I'm new to web development.

Comment: Welcome to web dev! This is a pretty complex issue for just starting out so i'd suggest looking into first: what `rem` is as a unit of measure. It is a relative unit unlike `px`. I'm referring to the values in `background-position`. I have a feeling the relative value of `rem` is set differently in Safari vs Chrome. There is a chance these two browsers set these values default differently and you may need to figure out a  master `root` value that will work for all browsers. Scroll to relative units in this doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units

Comment: You were absolutely right it was an issue with the rem values. All I had to do was set a default font-size value and it worked perfectly. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear it! Hope to see some contributions from you in there, thats a cool project for sure